# Puppeteer: add basic auth header for main page domain only, not for 3rd party requests

Tags: node.js, puppeteer, basic-authentication, google-chrome-headless

I'm trying to get puppeteer to send an `Authorization` header, without receiving a challenge, *for 1st/2nd-party requests only* - ie not to 3rd parties, and without unintended consequences. The main goals are to authenticate where needed and to avoid leaking the killer combination of `Authorization` + `Referer`

Using `page.authenticate()` won't work, because it requires a challenge. Using `page.setExtraHTTPHeaders()` sets the header, but then sends it on to third parties. Using `page.setRequestInterception()` allows me to introduce some conditional logic, and does address the main goals, but it appears to add a bunch of complexity and unintended consequences (eg around caching).

My specific use case is around webfonts, fwiw.

Here's how I've confirmed that the extra header is sent to a 3rd party with `page.setExtraHTTPHeaders` (in this case, httpbin)

Serve a simple page with an iframe to httpbin.org/headers:

```js
var http = require('http')

http.createServer(function (request, response) {
    console.log(request.headers)
    response.writeHead(200)
    response.end('<iframe src="http://httpbin.org/headers" width="100%" height="100%"></iframe>\n')
}).listen(8000)
```

Use puppeteer to fetch that page:

```js
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
const url = 'http://localhost:8000';

(async () => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch()

  const page = await browser.newPage()

  await page.setExtraHTTPHeaders({ Authorization: 'Basic dXNlcjpwYXNz' })
  //await page.authenticate({ username: 'user', password: 'pass' })
  await page.goto(url)
  await page.screenshot({path: '/tmp/headers.png'})

  await browser.close()
})()
```

Contents of the httpbin.org/headers response (captured on the wire with `tcpflow -c`):

```
 {
  "headers": {
    "Accept": "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9", 
    "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate", 
    "Accept-Language": "en-GB", 
    "Authorization": "Basic dXNlcjpwYXNz",  <----- Authorization is forwarded
    "Host": "httpbin.org", 
    "Referer": "http://localhost:8000/", 
    "Upgrade-Insecure-Requests": "1", 
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) HeadlessChrome/83.0.4103.0 Safari/537.36", 
    "X-Amzn-Trace-Id": "Root=1-5ecdb903-0c61b77370a47d894aa8aa7c"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `request.isNavigationRequest()` method to filter out any requests that are not for the main domain to limit when auth headers etc. are applied.

A similar issue was reported on the GitHub puppeteer project which lead to this method being added, the author gave this example [usage](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/issues/2627#issuecomment-393407765):

```
    // enable request interception
    await page.setRequestInterception(true);
    // add header for the navigation requests
    page.on('request', request => {
      // Do nothing in case of non-navigation requests.
      if (!request.isNavigationRequest()) {
        request.continue();
        return;
      }
      // Add a new header for navigation request.
      const headers = request.headers();
      headers['X-Just-Must-Be-Request-In-Main-Request'] = 1;
      request.continue({ headers });
    });
    // navigate to the website
    await page.goto('https://example.com');
```

Comment: to bad `setExtraHTTPHeaders` does not include an option to restrict to **NavigationRequest**